# Function with dplyr, tidyr and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr, tidyeval

How can I make a function that takes a column and uses that in dplyr, tidyr and ggplot?

```
df <- data.frame(date_col = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5), 
                 col_a = c('a','b','a','b','a','a','b','a','b'),
                 val_col = runif(9))
```

How do I write a function takes a parameter `param_col` instead of the hardcoded col_a

```
df %>% 
  group_by(date_col, col_a) %>% 
  summarise(val_col = sum(val_col)) %>% 
  complete(col_a, date_col) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date_col, val_col, color = col_a)) + 
  geom_line()
```

The dplyr and ggplot calls work in the code outlined below. But how should the `complete` call be written? Or should `complete_` be used?

Is there a more canonical way of doing this?

```
plot_nice_chart <- function(df, param_col) {

  enq_param_col <- enquo(param_col)
  str_param_col <- deparse(substitute(param_col))


  # aggregate data based on group_by_col, 
  # explicitly fill in NA's for missing to avoid interpolation
  df %>% 
     group_by(!!enq_param_col, date_col) %>%
     summarise(val_col = sum(val_col)) %>%
     complete(<what-should-be-here?>, date_col) %>%
     ggplot(aes_string("date_col", "val_col", color = str_param_col)) +
        geom_line()
}
```

Comment: can you give some example data?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are passing any function arguments to `complete`, so it seems like things should work as-is.  Is the function not working?

Comment: what should <what-should-be-here?> be replaced by to complete any missing levels in the combination of group_by_col and date_col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development version of *tidyr*, tidyr_0.6.3.9000, now uses `tidyeval`, so if you want to update to that you could use `!!` as you did in `group_by`.

```
plot_nice_chart <- function(df, param_col) {

     enq_param_col <- enquo(param_col)
     str_param_col <- deparse(substitute(param_col))
     str_param_col
     df %>%
          group_by(!!enq_param_col, date_col) %>%
          summarise(val_col = sum(val_col)) %>%
          ungroup() %>%
          complete(!!enq_param_col, date_col) %>%
          ggplot(aes_string("date_col", "val_col", color = str_param_col)) +
          geom_line()
}
```

Using the current version, you can use `complete_` with variables as strings.

```
plot_nice_chart <- function(df, param_col) {

     enq_param_col <- enquo(param_col)
     str_param_col <- deparse(substitute(param_col))

     df %>%
          group_by(!!enq_param_col, date_col) %>%
          summarise(val_col = sum(val_col)) %>%
          ungroup() %>%
          complete_( c(str_param_col, "date_col") ) %>%
          ggplot(aes_string("date_col", "val_col", color = str_param_col)) +
          geom_line()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. wrapping string arguments in a vector with `c` works. But why?

Comment: @Rickard I believe the `cols` argument needs to a character vector much like the `gather_cols` [argument of `gather_`](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/109#issuecomment-168024977) .

Comment: If I now want to use this function with another function. How should I proceed? e.g. c("col_a","col_b","col_c") %>% walk(~ plot_nice_chart(df, .) gives me "column  `.` is unknown"

Comment: It could be related to `deparse(substitute())` or how *purrr* works.  Try asking a new question for this new problem.  You may find it easier to get the development version of *tidyr* and work within `tidyeval`.

Comment: @Rickard Also, if you've switched to working with strings as inputs you'll need `rlang::sym` for *dplyr* but can work directly with the string for `aes_string` and `complete` (i.e., you don't need `deparse(substitute() )` ).